# Positioning content with Dynamic width using absolute positioning

Tags: css, dynamic, width, positioning, absolute

I'd live to position two divs in a container right next to each other which occupy 100% of the container together with a fixed amount of padding between the two. Is it possible to do so without knowing the width of either divs or using percentages. Hopefully this sample code will give some idea on what I'm trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2uTA/

```
.orange {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:45%;
  background-color:orange;
}
.yellow {
  width:auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}    

<!--sample html-->
<div style="position:relative;width:100%">
  <div class="orange">Orange Div</div>
  <div class="yellow">I want this div to start 10px to the right of the orange div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `.yellow`:

```
.yellow {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 45%
```

You can simply play with percentages until you're satisfied with the space between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try using float:left; margin-right:(according to your convenience in your page) in the class for yellow to place the orange and yellow next to each other in the container.

And as Davion said, you play with percentages and then you will get your spaces perfectly.

Comment: Thanks guys. I would like to use percentages for the divs themselves, but not for the padding between the two. I want the padding to always be 10px. Is there a way to say orange div width should be 45% with 10px right margin and yellow div should take the remaining width of the container? I've tried width=auto but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: We give width as width:auto in style for css. Trying giving the container width:100% and width of orange as 45% and remaining is the yellow which should be width:auto

Comment: @Depika width:auto doesn't work when using absolute positioning

Answer (score 0):

Try using following css code:

```
.orange {
  background-color:orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}

.yellow {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

Hope it should help you in achieving your purpose.

Comment: Thanks @ravk. I don't want to use percentage for the margin, I want to fix it and have the width for yellow just use the remaining width. Is there a way to do it. That's what I've actually been struggling with.

Comment: @SandeepAdi, add following to your `.yellow` class: `width: 50%;` `margin-left: 5px;` `right: 0;`

Comment: Changing the width on the yellow puts a scroll on the div(http://jsfiddle.net/C2uTA/2). It appears like there is no way to achieve what I'm trying without fixing the width on the container.